# How do i take action only if a service exists?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

trying to do away with skipping errors in my playbook. i want to take action only if a service exists.

```
  tasks:
  - name: check service exists
    win_service:
     name: god_mode
    register: service_info
```

this returns

```
"service_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "exists": false,
        "failed": false
```

im thinking something like this but its not working. tried different variations. hoping someone has some experience with this. thanks!

```
  - name: disable service god_mode
    win_service:
     name: god_mode
     state: stopped
    when: service_info == exists": true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary lookup isn't correct. It should look like this:

```
when: service_info.exists
```

Notice you don't need `== true`. Keep in mind it will fail if your variable is either undefined or just of type string. According to info you provided it's going to work though.

Comment: worked, thanks! curious as to how just using .exists works as exists is returned in the case of the service being there or not.

Comment: Item with key `exists` is returned always in your first task. If service does exists then value with key `exists` is `true` and `false` otherwise. As I mentioned in the answer this will fail if such item is not defined.